# Lua unexpected symbol near 'ď', which isn't there

Tags: unicode, lua, utf-8

I have following file content:

```
local t = {
    
    
}

return t
```

and this lines of code which loads it:

```
function koServer.loadDataFile(filename)
    local dataLoader, errorMsg = loadfile(filename)
    local data = nil
    
    if dataLoader then 
        local success, result = pcall(dataLoader)
        if success then
            net.log("Successfully loaded: " .. filename)
            data = result
        else
            net.log("Error loading " .. filename .. ": " .. result)
        end
    else
        net.log("Could not load " .. filename .. ": " .. (errorMsg or "unknown error"))
        -- data = {} 
    end
    
    return data
end
```

and it somehow gives error:

```
2023-09-06 12:12:00.392 INFO    LuaNET (Main): Could not load Z:\TKO\Scripts\ko_vipPlayerData.lua: [string "Z:\TKO\Scripts\ko_vipPlayerData.lua"]:1: unexpected symbol near 'ď'
```

despite the character not being there, even non-printable character viewer doesn't see them. When searching the file with total commander, it detects the symbol there, but when searching the file, it shows no search results. The symbol is not even visible in hex editor. What might be the issue?

I tried searching the file in hex editor, visual studio code, notepad.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found the solution, the hex editor showed it when loading the file, and not copying the content. It showed bytes `EF BB BF`, which translate to that symbol. And the file was saved using wrong formatting, it was UTF-8 with BOM, and not UTF-8. Also, not CRLF.